# React Router Dom routes are returning blank pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

My route setup returns a blank page with no error, the only thing that's showing up is the side menu. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import i18n from './i18n';
import Dash from "./pages/Dash";
import Prof from "./pages/Prof";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

 function App() {
  return (
   <Router>
    <Sidebar/>
    <Routes>
     <Route path='/' exact component={Dash} />
     <Route path='/profile' exact component={Prof} />
    </Routes>
  </Router>
 );
}
export default App;
```

**Dash.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import Dashboard from ".././components/Dashboard";
export default function Dash() {
 return (
<>
  <Dashboard />
</>
);
}
```

**Prof.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import Dashboard from ".././components/Profile";
export default function Prof() {
 return (
<>
  <Profile />
</>
);
}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using React Router Dom `v6` since you are using `Routes` instead of `Switch`, in which case it should be `element`, not `component`, the propriety where you pass that component for that route. Also, call the component when passing it like so:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import Dash from "./pages/Dash";
import Prof from "./pages/Prof";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Sidebar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Dash />} />
        <Route path="/profile" exact element={<Prof />} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

⚠️: notice it's `element={<Dash />}` and not `element={Dash}`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you use Routes object. You must use Routes > Route as a declaration. In order to go for what your trying which is to render a component based on url, you must use `Outlets`.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#outlet