# React Routes not display "/" page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

My Landing page displays fine until I encapsulate it within a Route, The Heading still loads as expected, but even the * page doesn't work.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" component={Landing} exact />
        <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} exact />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React router dom routes are returning blank pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219790/react-router-dom-routes-are-returning-blank-pages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **element prop** as follows:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} exact />
        <Route path="*" element={<PageNotFound />}} exact />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```