# Why is my react app showing a blank page currently?

Tags: reactjs

I am very new with React and am getting a blank screen when running 'yarn start'. I have been trying to figure this out for a while and have tried everything I could find. I have even tried making it a production build. This has been so frustrating. Help would be much appreciated.
Sam

```js
import { toast, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Home from './Components/Home/home';
import Profile from './Components/Profile/profile';
import SidePanel from './Components/SidePanel/sidePanel';
import SignIn from './Components/Signin/signin';
import Signup from './Components/Signup/Signup';


class App extends Component {
  showToast = (type, message) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 0:
        toast.warning(message)
        break;
      case 1:
        toast.success(message)
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  render(props) {
    return (< Router >
      <ToastContainer
        autoClose={2000}
        hideProgressBar={true}
        position={toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER}
      />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={prop => <Home {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/signin"
          render={prop => <SignIn showToast={this.showToast} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/signup"
          render={prop => <Signup showToast={this.showToast} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/profile"
          render={prop => <Profile showToast={this.showToast} {...props} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/chat"
          render={prop => <SidePanel showToast={this.showToast} {...props} />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    );
  };
};

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a screenshot of the console errors I am getting
[image: Constole Errors I am receiving]

Comment: Because you have an error in the console most likely.

Comment: Do you have a line like this `ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));` in your project? Probably in `index.js`? This will render you app component as the child of an HTML element with the ID `root`. That's the entry point for React if you will. I'm not using class components but the `render()` function does not take arguments, I think?

Comment: If you're using RRDV6, `Route` component uses the `element` prop to render a component. You can pass `props` to it as you normally would. Also, I think `exact` prop is no longer supported in this version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router Dom routes are returning blank pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219790/react-router-dom-routes-are-returning-blank-pages)