# React main page is not loading

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to develop an online shop in React. Trying to load app.js. I don't get any errors, just a blank page.

**App.js** as follows:

```
import AppRouter from "./components/AppRouter";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";

const App = observer(() => {
    const {user} = useContext(Context)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        check().then(data => {
            user.setUser(true)
            user.setIsAuth(true)
        }).finally(() => setLoading(false))
    }, [])

    if (loading) {
        return <Spinner animation={"grow"}/>
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <NavBar />
            <AppRouter />
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
});

export default App;
```

**NavBar.js** as follows:

```
import {NavLink, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";
import {ADMIN_ROUTE, LOGIN_ROUTE, SHOP_ROUTE} from "../utils/consts";

const NavBar = observer(() => {
    const {user} = useContext(Context)
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const logOut = () => {
        user.setUser({})
        user.setIsAuth(false)
    }

    return (
        <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Container>
                <NavLink style={{color:'white'}} onClick={SHOP_ROUTE}>Victoria's Tech Store


</NavLink>
                {user.isAuth ?
                    <Nav className="ml-auto" style={{color: 'white'}}>
                        <Button
                            variant={"outline-light"}
                            onClick={() => navigate.push(ADMIN_ROUTE)}
                        >
                            Admin
                        </Button>
                        <Button
                            variant={"outline-light"}
                            onClick={() => logOut()}
                            className="ml-2"
                        >
                            Logout
                        </Button>
                    </Nav>
                    :
                    <Nav className="ml-auto" style={{color: 'white'}}>
                        <Button variant={"outline-light"} onClick={() => (LOGIN_ROUTE)}>Login</Button>
                    </Nav>
                }
            </Container>
        </Navbar>

    );
});

export default NavBar;
```

**AppRouter.js** as follows:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Routes, Route, Router, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import {SHOP_ROUTE} from "../utils/consts";

const AppRouter = observer(() => {
    const {user} = useContext(Context);
    const Navigate = useNavigate();

    console.log(user)
    return (
        <Router>
                    <Routes>
            {user.isAuth && authRoutes.map(({path, Element}) =>
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={Element} exact/>
            )}
            {publicRoutes.map(({path, Element}) =>
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={Element} exact/>
            )}
            <Navigate to={SHOP_ROUTE}/>
            </Routes>
        </Router>
    );
});

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: Can you add console log in the components and see if they are printing meaningful values properly ? Also check if any error is thrown in console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Router Dom routes are returning blank pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219790/react-router-dom-routes-are-returning-blank-pages)

Answer (score 0):

Look in the browser console for any error messages, maybe what's causing the issue is some content that isn't being loaded like a file not imported or something along those lines.